# Rasa Slots are getting stored as a list instead of string

Tags: rasa-core, rasa

I facing an issue that my location slot is considered a list instead of string sometimes

I am submitting my code link:

- TULSA - worked (string)
- tulsa - worked (string)
- Tulsa - didn’t work ( List)

Don’t know why it is behaving like this?

link for my code: [11:35 AM] Omkar Patil

https://github.com/omkarcpatilgithub/Rasa_episode8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give more utterances for my nlu.md file, with this my issue got resolved

reference: https://forum.rasa.com/t/slot-is-storing-as-a-list/31063/2